# Current day and Previous 30 day distinct count

Tags: sql, hive, count, distinct-values

I have a data set that I’m trying to join back to each other to get the previous 30 day count. The initial table has a distinct count of id that is given for a day. My end goal is getting the current day count and previous x (current example is 30) day count  by joining by itself so I can calculate a rolling 30 average from day 1 to day 30 ago.

The structure is already determined so far as such but unsure if best way.

The original table is

```
Day.       id.               group
12/1/2020.  1.               A
12/2/2020.  1.               A
12/3/2020.  2.              B
12/3/2020.  3.              B
12/3/2020.  4.              B
12/4/2020.  1.              A
12/4/2020.  2.              A
12/4/2020.  3.              A
12/4/2020.  4.              A
.
.
.
1/30/2021.  1.               A
```

I use the original table to do a distinct count per day

```
Day.       Count_prev30.   group
12/1/2020.  83.               A
12/2/2020.  93.               A
12/3/2020.  103.              B
12/4/2020.  126.              A
.
.
.
1/4/2021.  166.               A
```

Currently I take this table and also do a date_sub(partition_date_et, 29) partition_date_et_30 and have another set where

```
Day.       Day_previous_30 Count_current.   group
1/1/2021.  12/01/2020       123.               A
1/2/2021.  12/02/2020       133.               A
1/3/2021.  12/03/2020       143.               B
1/4/2021.  12/04/2020       166.               A
.
.
.
1/31/2021.  12/31/2020       186.               A
```

I join these data set so I with Day and Day_previous_30

```
Day.       Day_previous_30 Count_current.   count_prev30      group
1/1/2021.  12/01/2020       123.            83                  A
1/2/2021.  12/02/2020       133.            93                  A
1/3/2021.  12/03/2020       143.            103                 A
1/4/2021.  12/04/2020       166.            126                 B
.
.
.
.
infinite dates
```

I am not sure if this is the best method to get current day count and current previous in my aggregation For 1/1/2021 my count average is Count_current + Count_prev30 /2.

Just want to see how others would achieve this if there is a better way.  I do not think there is a count distinct window function such as sum over.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  What results are you looking for?  And how do you get that 2020-12-01 is 29 days before 2021-01-01?  And where does `count_current` come from?

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had explained clearly. Updated with more context. @GordonLinoff

Comment: Are those 2 sets of data fixed or are you obtaining them for one single table?

Comment: @banana_99 I’m obtaining from one table.

Comment: @epv could you please show us your one table so we can think of something easier? There are lots of functions with which this can be easily achieved in one step.

Comment: @banana_99 thank you for the request.  It has been enhanced with original source

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data for each day, you can use:

```
select day, count(*),
       sum(count(*)) over (order by day range between 29 preceding and current row)
from t
group by day;
```

Your code shows a `group` column, but the question doesn't mention it at all, so this just ignores it.